# List comprehension: does it respect the order of the list taken as its base?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, iteration, list-comprehension

After running a script that appends values to a list such as:

```py
list_of_c = []
for value in list_of_b:
    # do something with value
    returns new_value
    list_of_c.append(new_value)
```

I want to edit the resulting `list_of_c`, without affecting order in which the items are in there. Can I achieve that with the following list comprehension, or does it ignore the ordering in the list `list_of_c`?

I'm taking a rounding operation as an example.

```py
list_of_d = [round(value, 4) for value in list_of_c]
```

More specifically, in this example case, if I have the following:

```py
list_of_c = [a, b, c, d, e]
```

If running the loop on `list_of_c`, would I be sure the get the resulting
`list_of_d` in the following order?

```py
list_of_d = [round_a, round_b, round_c, round_d, round_e]
```

Comment: is your returns new_a a REAL return? List conserve order

Comment: No, list comprehensions iterate over the iterable in the ordered defined by it's iterator. In the case of `list` objects, they are insertion-ordered. A list comprehension is essentially *exactly equivalent* to a for-loop that appends to a list.

Comment: @Wonka thank you for your reply! No it is not a real return, sorry about that, it's just a set of operations that results in the variable `new_a` !

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you for your reply! Just to make sure I've got it, does that mean that if I use this list comprehension the other the variables are output is not necessarily the same as the order in which the variables appear in the first list?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. To put it simply: list comprehensions give you the same order that you would get from a for-loop. So it *will* preserve the order of the original list you are iterating over

Comment: Thank you @juanpa.arrivillaga I think that was exactly what I wanted to know! Tried to update the question, but I guess it is marked as closed, even though I wasn't sure about the reply from the one that it based the DUPLICATE status on! 
So thank you!